# Get int from byte array by offset

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, byte, chunks

I am new to C++. Can't get int from byte array by offset.

When i read directly from memory all works fine and i am gettings 100 - this is correct value

```
int base = 0x100;
int offset = 0x256;

int easy = memory->ReadMemory<int>(base + offset); // easy = 100
```

But if i try to get a chunk of bytes and read from them, here problem comes

```
template<class T>
T FromBuffer(uint8_t* buffer, size_t offset)
{
    T t_buf = 0;
    memcpy(&t_buf, buffer + offset, sizeof(T));
    return t_buf;
}

uint8_t* ReadBytes(DWORD Address, int Size)
{
    auto arr = new uint8_t[Size];
    ReadProcessMemory(TargetProcess, (LPVOID)Address, arr, sizeof(arr), 0);
    return arr;
}

auto bytes = memory->ReadBytes(base, 2500);
int hard = *((unsigned int *)&bytes[offset]); // hard = -842150451
uint32_t hard2 = memory->FromBuffer<uint32_t>(bytes, offset); // hard2 = 3452816845
```

With C# it would easy like this

```
int hard = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, offset);
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` does not do what you think it does. `arr` is an `uint8_t *`, therefore `sizeof(arr)` is the same as `sizeof(uint8_t *)`. That's obviously not what you want.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you, now it's works fine.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and replace the explicit memory management with either `std::vector<uint8_t>` or `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` (the fundamental difference is that the first stores the length, while the second expects you to keep track of it yourself)

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you for advice

Comment: I'm no expert here but isn't this undefined behaviour? AFAIK you can't cast an array of `uint8_t` to `unsigned int` without breaking the strict aliasing rule. My understanding is that you can cast any type pointer to `char*` to view individual bytes but do it the other way and all bets are off.

Comment: @Fibbles i am to noob to answer such questions) But it now working fine for me.

Comment: Maybe @BenVoigt can give you a more authoritative answer in that regard. I believe the correct way to achieve what you're setting out to do is (rather than casting) to read each byte as a `char`, bitshift them into separate `unsigned ints` then bitwise or them together to get the final result. I'm not confident enough in what I'm saying to write an answer though.

Comment: @Fibbles: `memcpy` avoids all strict aliasing issues, you can memcpy from a buffer owned by `std::vector` just the same as a buffer you allocated yourself.

Comment: @BenVoigt I wasn't aware of that but even so he's not using memcpy when assigning a value to `hard`. He's just straight up casting `uint8_t*` to `unsigned int*` and then dereferencing the value and storing in an `int`.

Comment: @Fibbles: Yes, `hard` is undefined behavior (in the existing code, switching to `std::vector` changes nothing) and `hard2` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting this type of C# code to C++ doesn't make any sense, you were forced to do some whacky stuff in C# because doing this type of operation is not what C# was intended for.

You do not need to create a dynamic buffer and do any of that wizardry.  Just do:

```cpp
template <class T>
T RPM(void* addr)
{
    T t;
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, addr, &t, sizeof(t), nullptr);
    return t;
}

int RPM(addr + offset);
```